# File Uploaded to a Case using Chatter vs File's Related List

Tags: community

Is there any way to see on a **ContentDocumentLink** record for a certain a case whether a file was uploaded to the case using **Chatter** or the **Files** related list. I could not find any fields on the ContentDocumentLink object that would have that information. Please advise.

Basically, I am trying to write code that will make Visibility on files uploaded via Chatter >>> internal. BUT if File is uploaded via Related List >>> AllUsers. The 1st case is applicable for our support team. 2nd case for Community users.

Thank You!